# Updating an item/document takes between 1-2 seconds in a small index

Tags: java, lucene

We have a small index - less than 1MB in size and covering roughly 10,000 documents. The only fields that are stored are quite short which explains the small index size.

After the documents are loaded into the index, an update of an existing document can take between 1 and 2 seconds (there's quite a variance in this range though). We've tried utilizing various best practices (such as those in the Lucene wiki) but can't find what's wrong. We've even gone ahead and are now using RAMDirectory to remove the possibility of IO being the problem.

Is this really the performance to expect?

**UPDATE**
As requested below, I'm adding some more details:

- We're treating Lucene as a black-box, we just time the amount of time it takes to reindex/update an object. We don't know what's going on inside.
- The objects (or documents, in Lucene's terms) are quite small, with a total size of a 2KB of data each.

Comment: I am not really familiar with Lucene, but have you tried using a profiler to find out what is going on? You might also want to mention a few details about the document that might be pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet outlining your entire update procedure would help. Are you committing after each update? This is not necessary and for top performance you must use Near Realtime Readers. Newer Lucene versions have an NRTManager that handles most of the boilerplate involved.

In many cases the best practice is to commit only rarely or never (except when shutting down). If your service shuts down ungracefully, you lose your index, but even if you didn't, you'd have to rebuild it upon restart anyway to account for all the changes that happened in the meantime.